# How can we revive our chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

Sadly participation in our [general chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/499/german-language-and-usage) became low to none.

Communicating through chat is vital to a healthy site. Only there we can discuss matters of the site's design or its content. In chat we may find definitions on where the site should go, and we can discuss how to improve poor content.

New users will benefit from help through chat the same as do *alte Hasen* who would like to hear other people's opinion before they comment or vote too hastily.

In addition we can quickly provide help on smaller issues in spelling or grammar for noth beginners, and the advanced. This may eventually lead to a boost in questions that may have evolved from an ongoing chat discussion.

But how do we bring back life to our chat?

Comment: Es ist ja nicht nur der Chat. Wir haben laut area51.stackexchange.com auch zu wenig Fragen. Wir sollten ca. 15 am Tag haben und haben 2,6 pro Tag. Alles andere ist zwar prima, aber Chat und Menge der Fragen nicht. Gibt es vielleicht andere SE-Seiten, die ähnliche Probleme hatten? Was haben die gemacht? Können wir deren Erfahrung auf uns anwenden?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using SO for years now with a high reputation and I never used the chat. It's a nice thing to have and maybe useful in such situations as noted in the question. I don't think we need an active chat as a proof of traffic and health.

Comment: How comes you say that? I do remember you were in chat quite often. I also remember that you asked for further discussions in chat in several of your commments.

Comment: @Takkat: I have been in the GL&U-Chat, yes, but not in the SE-Chat.

Comment: @user unknown: It seems you mean _SO_ (StackOverflow) when you write _SE_ (StackExchange). SE is the network to which both SO and GLU belong.

Comment: @chirlu: Oh, yes, of course! Corrected. Many thanks.